# Minha função vue.js para conversão de moeda retorna NaN

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Minha função vue.js para conversão de moeda que usa a API de http://free.currencyconverterapi.com retorna NaN, ao inves de retornar a conversão de moeda.

```html
<template>
    <div class="conversor">
        <h2>{{moedaA}} Para {{moedaB}}</h2>
        <input type="text" v-model="moedaA_value" v-bind:placeholder="moedaA">
        <input type="button" value="Converter" v-on:click="converter">
        <h2>{{moedaB_value}}</h2>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "Conversor",
    props: ["moedaA","moedaB"],

    data(){
          return {
              moedaA_value :"",
              moedaB_value : 0
          };
    },
    methods:{
        converter(){
            let de_para = this.moedaA + "_" + this.moedaB;


            let url = "http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q="+
                de_para
            +"&compact=ultra&apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

            fetch(url)

                .then(res=>{
                    return res.json()
                })
                .then(json =>{

                    let cotacao = json[de_para].val;
                    this.moedaB_value = (cotacao * parseFloat(this.moedaA_value)).toFixed(
                            2
                    )
                })
        }
    }  
};
</script>

<!-- O scoped serve para limitar o estilo apenas ao arquivo em que a tag é usada-->  
<style scoped>
</style>
```

Comment: O que dá `console.log(url)`? Essa chave da API é tua/verdadeira? isto é um espaço público... não deves colocar aqui dados privados.

Comment: Obrigado pelo toque da Key, não tinha me atentado, console.log(url) me traz a url correta, ao usar a url no navegador ele me traz o seguinte json                   {
USD_BRL: 3.939041
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O teu erro estava na maneira como estás a extrair o valor do `json` que recebes. Essa chave `.val` não existe, deves extrair diretamente com `json[de_para]`.

Um exemplo a funcionar seria assim:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#vue-app',
  name: "Conversor",
  props: {
    moedaA: {
      default: 'USD'
    },
    moedaB: {
      default: 'EUR'
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      moedaA_value: "",
      moedaB_value: 0
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getUrl(currencies) {
      return [
        "http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=",
        currencies,
        "&compact=ultra&apiKey=af285a9098c9614181bd"
      ].join('');
    },
    converter() {
      const de_para = this.moedaA + "_" + this.moedaB;
      const url = this.getUrl(de_para);
      fetch(url)
        .then(res => {
          return res.json()
        })
        .then(json => {
          const cotacao = json[de_para];
          const valor = (cotacao * parseFloat(this.moedaA_value)).toFixed(2)
          this.moedaB_value = `${valor} ${this.moedaB}`;
        })
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="vue-app">
  <div class="conversor">
    <h2>{{moedaA}} Para {{moedaB}}</h2>
    <input type="text" v-model="moedaA_value" v-bind:placeholder="moedaA">
    <input type="button" value="Converter" v-on:click="converter">
    <h2>{{moedaB_value}}</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado, realmente .val não era precisso no codigo, me ajudou muito